# Load Balancer with Multiple Backend Instances and Weightage Distribution in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a load balancer in Google Cloud Platform that distributes traffic across multiple backend instance groups while also specifying weightage for each backend. My goal is to achieve an equal distribution of traffic (50-50) between the two backend instance groups.

I have followed the official documentation and online tutorials to create instance groups, backend services, URL maps, and forwarding rules, but I'm struggling to configure the weightage distribution.

Here's what I've done so far:

Created two instance groups: instance-group-1 and instance-group-2.
Created two backend services: backend-service-1 and backend-service-2, each associated with its respective instance group.
Created a URL map with path-based routing, routing requests to the two backend services based on the paths.
Created a target HTTP proxy and global forwarding rule.
However, I'm unsure how to configure the weightage distribution for each backend service to achieve the desired 50-50 sharing of traffic between the two instance groups.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to configure the weightage distribution in this scenario? Any insights, examples, or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By default, the Load Balancer distribution is Round Robin. i.e. an even distribution to all the backend. Why do you need more?

Comment: I have two backend instance groups—a static, unmanaged group and a dynamic, managed group set to autoscale. In certain scenarios, the unmanaged group might have only one instance (the default configuration), while the managed group can dynamically adjust its instances, ranging from a minimum of two to a maximum of ten. Given this mix of instance counts, I'm curious if the Load Balancer's distribution will still be evenly spread across instances or groups.

I want it to be like 70:30 by setting at load balancer level.

Comment: Which type of load balancer do you use?

Comment: HTTP load balancer.

Comment: It's not possible to achieve this with an HTTP LB. It's only possible with a TCP/UDP LB, a passthrough LB, not a proxy (HTTP) LB. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/configure-weighted-netlb